# Getting value in dd but not in specific div in laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 to fetch data from database in the controller, which i am fetching successfully, i tried to view it using `dd` (in controller and in blade file as well) and received the array. Here is my code

This is my controller function

```
public function show($roomAd)
{
    $showRoom = RoomAd::where('id',$roomAd)->get();
    // dd($showRoom);
    return view('seller/singleprod',compact('showRoom'));
}
```

here is my `singleprod.balde.php` file

```
<div class="wrapper row">
                {{-- {{dd($showRoom)}} --}}
                @if (!empty($showRoom))


                    <div class="preview col-md-6">

                        <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                            <div class="" id=""><img src="{{ URL::to('/image') }}/{{ $showRoom->advert_image }}"
                                    alt="room-ad-{{ $showRoom->id }}" /></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="details col-md-6">
                        <h3 class="product-title">{{ $showRoom->advert_title }}</h3>
                        
                        <p class="product-description">{{ $showRoom->advert_desc }}</p>
                        <h4 class="price">Rent: <span>${{ $showRoom->rent_with_duration }}</span></h4>
                        
                        <h5 class="sizes">size:
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">{{ $showRoom->room_size }}</span>
                        </h5>
                        <h5 class="area">Area:
                            <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                            <span>{{ $showRoom->area }}</span>
                            <span class="color blue"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</button>
                            <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span
                                    class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @else
                    {{ 'Error' }}
                @endif
            </div>
```

My problem is i am not able to retrieve the data on specific div like `$showRoom->advert_image`, it shows the error
`Exception Property [advert_image] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: resolved by my own, i used `$showRoom[0]->id` instead of `$showRoom->id`, it showed the result on blade as well.

Answer (score 1):

don't use get() use first() if you are only getting single record.

```
 $showRoom = RoomAd::where('id',$roomAd)->first();
```

or the better way is to use findOrFail()

```
 $showRoom = RoomAd::findOrFail($roomAd);
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, i resolved by my own, i used `$showRoom[0]->id` instead of `$showRoom->id`, it showed the result on blade as well.

Comment: but this is not the good way. its up to you ): .

Comment: ahan ok then i will try ur method, thanks for your response... :)